# Delete following observations when goal has been reached

Tags: r, dataframe

Given the dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3),
  Start = c(0,8,150,200,6,7,60),
  Stop = c(5,60,170,210,NA,45,80))


  ID  Start Stop Dummy
1  1     0    5     0
2  1     8   60     1
3  1   150  170     1
4  1   200  210     1
5  2     6   NA     0
6  3     7   45     0
7  3    60   80     1
```

For each ID, I would like to keep all rows until `Start[i+1] - Stop[i] >= 28`, and then delete the following observations of that ID

In this example, the output should be

```
   ID Start Stop Dummy
1  1     0    5     0
2  1     8   60     1
5  2     6   NA     0
6  3     7   45     0
7  3    60   80     1
```

---

I ended up having to set NA's to a value easy to identify later and the following code

```
df$Stop[is.na(df$Stop)] = 10000
df$diff <- df$Start-c(0,df$Stop[1:length(df$Stop)-1])
space <- with(df, unique(ID[diff<28]))
df2 <- subset(df, (ID %in% space & diff < 28) | !ID %in% space)
```

Comment: you mean `if` <28 instead of `until` ?

Comment: @docendo I guess the rule should be read as "exclude if X", with the default being to keep. For ID 2, the condition cannot be evaluated, so nothing is excluded. That's the only way I can make sense of it, anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[,{ 
  w = which( shift(Start,type="lead") - Stop >= 28 )
  if (length(w)) .SD[seq(w[1])] else .SD
}, by=ID]

#    ID Start Stop
# 1:  1     0    5
# 2:  1     8   60
# 3:  2     6   NA
# 4:  3     7   45
# 5:  3    60   80
```

`.SD` is the Subset of Data associated with each `by=ID` group.

Answer (score 0):

```
p <- which(df$Start[2:nrow(df)]-df$Stop[1:(nrow(df)-1)] >= 28)
df <- df[p,]
```

Assuming you want to keep entries where next entry start if higher than giben entry stop by 28 or more

The result is:

```
>p 2 3 
> df[p,]
  ID Start Stop
2  1     8   60
3  1   150  170
```

start in row 2 ( i + 1 = 2) is higher than stop in row 1 (i=1) by 90.

Or, if by *until* you mean the reverse condition, then

```
df <- df[which(df$Start[2:nrow(df)]-df$Stop[1:(nrow(df)-1)] < 28),]
```

Inclusion of NA in your data frame got me thinking. You have to be very careful how you word your condition. If you want to keep all the cases where difference between next start and stop is less than 28, then the above statement will do.
However, if you want to keep all cases EXCEPT when difference is 28 or more, then you should

```
p <- which((df$Start[2:nrow(df)]-df$Stop[1:(nrow(df)-1)] >= 28))
rp <-  which((!is.element(1:nrow(df),p)))
df <- df[rp,]
```

As it will include the unknown difference.

Comment: Hmm, did you take a look at the result?

Answer (score 0):

Create a diff column.

```
df$diff<-df$Start-c(0,df$Stop[1:length(df$Stop)-1])
```

Subset on the basis of this column

```
df[df$diff<28,]
```

PS: I have converted 'NA' to 0. You would have to handle that anyway.

Comment: It seems that they want to do this by group of ID

Comment: Converting NA  to 0 may not be a good idea, since the two mean different things: "start time is 0", as opposed to "time in unknown". The fact that the data has both, 0 and NA, the distinction might be important and it’s best not to substitute one for the other.